# Is anyone else integrating Spring Actuator endpoints with New Relic? Or is this redundant?

Tags: newrelic, spring-boot-actuator

I think New Relic does not have the httptrace/info/metrics that spring actuator has. So I am planning to use Spring Actuator endpoints in New Relic. Do other people do this? Or does New Relic have some way to show httptrace/info/metrics without exposing endpoints collecting httptrace/info/metrics info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really integrate an actuator with new relic, but rather **micrometer** which is an under-the-hood implementation of the metrics in spring boot 2 applications.

Spring boot actuator's `metrics` endpoint indeed can show the data (that is relevant for the current time snapshot) maintained by the micrometer, but that's only for your convenience.

In general you should configure micrometer to integrate with New Relic (which is a perfectly valid use case of course, and yes, many people use integrations like this, I used to do this with data dog, prometheus in my career for example).

The tutorial of integration micrometer-new-relic integration can be found [Here](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/new-relic)